# How can I show a selection list of widgets in my application?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

I want to show widgets list from my application with onclick event.

[image]

I want to show this widget list

[image]

I tried this code but not work

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_PICK);
context.startActivity(pickIntent);
```

Comment: Can you try [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Pinning)?

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is better than I wanted :D

Comment: ne demek, kolay gelsin :)

Comment: Eyvallah teşekürler :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this codes. Thank you Aytek Sökmen.

[This link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Pinning)

```
cid = note.getId();
MyNotesWidgetActivity.widgetProcess = "create";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = context.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager.class);

    ComponentName myProvider = new ComponentName(context, MyNotesWidget.class);
    if (appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported()) {

        Intent pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent = new Intent();

        PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, cid, pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null, successCallback);
    }
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_CAR_DOCK);
    mActivity.startActivity(i);
}
```